# Change docker mode to experimental in google cloud provider

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am using google cloud platform.

I created a cluster and i want to use criu feature of docker to do that i need to change docker mode to experimental.
I enter the node uisng ssh and enter etc/docker to change key.json file and add experimental parm to true. 
This command:

```
echo "{\"experimental\": true}" >> /etc/docker/key.json
```

gave me the error message `-bash: key.json: Permission denied`

How can i change docker mode?

*Update: change the key.json file using sudo vi but after i restarted docker using the command: `sudo systemctl restart docker` the docker still experimental = false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added daemon.json file in /etc/docker with the content:

```
{"experimental": true}
```

and restarted the docker service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

After the restart docker was in the experimental mode.